# Pass argument in main method when class extends another class in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to run a script for `asterisk-java` as below. I have added a `main` method and calling the `service` method inside it as follows:

```
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiChannel;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiException;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.AgiRequest;
import org.asteriskjava.fastagi.BaseAgiScript;

public class HelloAgiScript extends BaseAgiScript
{
    public void service(AgiRequest request, AgiChannel channel)
            throws AgiException
    {
        // Answer the channel...
        answer();

        // ...say hello...
        streamFile("welcome");

    // ...and hangup.
        hangup();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
    HelloAgiScript asteriskService = new HelloAgiScript();
    asteriskService.service(request, channel);
    }    
}
```

When I try to compile it with the following command:

`javac -cp asterisk-java.jar HelloAgiScript.java`

I get this error:

```
HelloAgiScript.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        asteriskService.service(request, channel);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable request
  location: class HelloAgiScript
HelloAgiScript.java:24: error: channel has private access in AgiOperations
        asteriskService.service(request, channel);
                                         ^
2 errors
```

How can I pass the arguments to the instance of the `service` method inside the `main` method?

Comment: That's expected. Both arguments provided in the call `asteriskService.service(request, channel);` are not defined inside `main` method.

Comment: I've never heard of asterisk java before, so I just googled it and read the tutorial linked from the home page: https://asterisk-java.org/tutorial/. It explains that a script is supposed to be run by a server. You don't write the main method. You deloy your class inside a server, that will call your method. Read the tutorial. That's what it's for.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the argument as the object of `AgiRequest` and `AgiChannel` class  to `service()` method call.

As in your case both `request` and `channel` variable is not created. That's why you are getting error `Can't find symbol`

Your main method should be like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    HelloAgiScript asteriskService = new HelloAgiScript();
    AgiRequest request = new AgiRequest();
    AgiChannel channel = new AgiChannel();
    asteriskService.service(request, channel);
 }
```

Comment: I tried your solution. I am getting this error: `AgiRequest is abstract. Cannot be instantiated`.

Comment: @Laxman, As suggested by **JB Nizet** in your post comment. It should be running on a server. And you no need to have main method for it. The server will be calling your service method. Please go through this [tutorial](https://asterisk-java.org/tutorial/)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't put any parameters into your main method from the command line. You should write something like

```
javac -cp asterisk-java.jar par1, par2
```

But, first of all, you should define which parameter should be your inner parameter like

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    HelloAgiScript asteriskService = new HelloAgiScript();
    AgiRequest request = args[0];
    AgiChannel channel = args[1];
    asteriskService.service(request, channel);
 }
```

Look [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/command-line-argument)

Comment: Hey Dred, How can you expect string to assign to an object at `AgiRequest request = args[0];`

Comment: @DKAnsh, hi. It's only a common example. Actually, I don't know what is AgiRequest and AgiChannel. Is it possible that its his own classes and its like a String. Anyway, question was about _How can I pass the arguments to the instance_

Comment: They are modules from `asterisk-java`. I am compiling them using a `jar` file.

Comment: Ok. If after first answer you haven't any exception, it's Ok that you don't accept my answer.